# Is there a way to determine why my react app is showing a blank page eventhough i routed it correctly on cpanel

Tags: reactjs, cpanel

here is the code in which i used for routing using the subdirectory

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Router basename={"/build"}>
    <Provider {...stores}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={login} />
        <Route
          path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Tardiness`}
          component={MainMenu}
        />
        <Route
          path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Resources`}
          component={Dashboard}
        />
        <Route
          path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/company`}
          component={Company}
        />
        <Route
          path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/admin`}
          component={Admin}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  </Router>
);



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

this is my htaccess file

and my homepage would be website.com/build

basically i do not know where to look for the issue regarding it not displaying for some reason

Comment: Are you reaching home page correctly? or you're unable to access the homepage as well? If not then try adding
`"homepage": "WEBSITEURL",`
above `name` in your package.json

Comment: i mean i added it. it still did not work

Comment: try logging ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}, i know its not the best way to debug but it will help you to know if URL is correct.

Furthermore if you have the homepage as website.com/build then you wont need `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` as prefix to your Links as they are relative.

Try removing `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` from path.

Comment: i followed some instructions on the web most of them added `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to their routes is it not important for the app within public_html/build?

Comment: If you can log the `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` and let me know what you're getting back, I'll be able to help you more.

Comment: FYI, if you're using `react-router-dom` then the `Switch` only returns the first matching path, and all your routes match `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`so this will only render the login page unless you specify the `exact` prop on your home route.

Comment: i did delete the ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL} from the paths and it worked now the issue was when i type the url website.com/build/admin it returns a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this as an answer as comment resolved the question.

Path needs to be relative to the base URL. Removing `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` will make it work as expected.